# PostgreSQL function in database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I created a function in PostgreSQL, I call this function in java using JDBC. I'm not sure if it's possible that this function works for every schema. I mean, what if I don't have any schema?

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to create functions in database and not in a specific schema?

Comment: Put it in the `public` schema? That's bound to exist.

Comment: Also then reference it by schema i.e. public.function()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official documentation

> If a schema name is included, then the function is created in the specified schema. Otherwise it is created in the current schema.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html

> A database contains one or more named schemas, which in turn contain tables. **Schemas also contain other kinds of named objects, including data types, functions, and operators**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html

So I believe you can't